# What is the name of this current called in this regulator datasheet?

Tags: current, voltage-regulator, datasheet

Which parameter in [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl780.pdf) data sheet is the default current flowing from the input to the ground regardless of the load current?

In my case an 12V input will be regulated to 5V by the TL780-05. So to estimate the total power dissipation I will use the following formula:

Preg = (I_n × 12) + (I_load × (12-5))

My problem is I don't know how they name I_n in the regulator datasheets, so I got stuck. Where in the datasheet I can find I_n? And is that always named same way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the one:

[image]

So typically 5 mA, maximum 8 mA

How to quickly find that: I know it's a current so I look for any parameter specified in A (or mA, uA) in the UNIT column. Then I look at each and see
if that could be the one.

There will be a small increase with increasing load current, see the line under the red rectangle.

Answer (score 5):

In that particular data sheet, they seem to be calling it "Input Bias Current". A more common term is "Quiescent Current".

Answer (score 2):

It's called input bias current and is on page 3 of the data sheet you linked.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you can ignore this bias current as it is small enough.

What you should be concerned about is voltage drop on regulator multiplied by load current.

For example if you have 12V input, 5V output and expected load current 3A - the power dissipation on regulator equial

```
P = (12-5)*3 = 7*3 = 21W
```

Load will *take* `P = 5V*3A = 15W (41.2%)` with *power loss* of `21W (58.3%)` -- the circuit is very inefficient, produces a lot of heat and requires bulky radiator.

If your circuit is not critical to some power 'noise' then solution based on [LM2596](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf), [LM2576](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576hv.pdf), [MP1484](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/277/MP1484-1186021.pdf), [MP1584](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP1584/document_id/204/), [MP2307](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/MP2307_r1.9.pdf) is more desirable due higher efficiency.

Of course you are not limited by these *ICs* and can use any other DC-DC converter.

[MPS](https://www.monolithicpower.com/products/dc-dc-power-conversion/switching-regulators.html),
[TI](http://www.ti.com/power-management/non-isolated-dc-dc-switching-regulators/overview.html),
[ST](https://www.st.com/en/power-management/dc-dc-switching-converters.html)
[RENESAS](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/power-management/dc-dc-converters.html),
[ON](https://www.onsemi.com/products/power-management/dc-dc-controllers-converters-regulators/converters),
[INFINEON](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/dc-dc-converters/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAk7TuBRDQARIsAMRrfUY20P4sWojixFcGB4zJJmec3hcqLNbX-xNQntlf-PzKBdoD6ltY7vIaAn7vEALw_wcB&ef_id=Cj0KCQiAk7TuBRDQARIsAMRrfUY20P4sWojixFcGB4zJJmec3hcqLNbX-xNQntlf-PzKBdoD6ltY7vIaAn7vEALw_wcB:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!719!3!318399575021!p!!g!!dc%20dc%20converter)

[DIGIKEY](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/power-supplies-board-mount/dc-dc-converters/922?k=dc-dc),
[MOUSER](https://www.mouser.com/Power/DC-DC-Converters/_/N-brvxe),
[10 Best Electronics Suppliers](https://www.instructables.com/community/10-Best-Electronics-Suppliers/)